# Meaning of "gkbrです"

Tags: expressions, idioms, internet-slang, animals

I have noticed the usage of `gkbrです` in sentences not related to the [G](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B4%E3%82%AD%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA) insect:

> 田中さんに掘り返されたことでgkbrです。
>
> 恐怖でgkbrですが続きテツヤ待機。

Does it mean "I am afraid and want to crawl under the furniture"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [ja.wikipedia page on GKBR](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GKBR), it can be ゴキブリ as well as:

> ｶﾞｸｶﾞｸﾌﾞﾙﾌﾞﾙ - 恐怖で震えるさまを表す擬態語。

So it'd be "GaKu BuRu," onomatopoeia that represents fearful trembling.

It's some 2ch slang, of course.

Here also is [an entry on the nicovideo dictionary](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/gkbr)

Comment: [ガクガク](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%AC%E3%82%AF) denotes wobbling knees, [ブルブル](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB) denotes a trembling body.